# Как упростить хранение данных в памяти Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, память, arduino, хранение-данных

Начал играться с бегущей строкой на базе диодных матриц, используя регистры и Arduino Uno. В общем и целом, все работает как надо. Программа заняла 4,6 байт из возможных 32 кбайт, а переменные 554 байт из 2 кбайт. Но когда я реализовал ввод слов из вне (терминала) для последующего вывода на бегущую строку ситуация сместилась в такую сторону: 7,5 байт для программы и 1242 байт для переменных. То есть увеличил в ~2 раза... И сам код получился довольно таки не лаконичным и однообразным. Не могли бы вы подсказать как упростить мой код?

Алфавит насчитывает 96 символов и хранится в таком виде:

```
byte A[] = { 0x7C, 0x12, 0x11, 0x12, 0x7C };  // А
byte a[] = { 0x20, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x78 };  // а
byte B[] = { 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x31 };  // Б  
byte b[] = { 0x3C, 0x4A, 0x4A, 0x4A, 0x31 };  // б
byte V[] = { 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36 };  // В
byte v[] = { 0x7C, 0x54, 0x54, 0x28, 0x00 };  // в
.....
```

Терминал не понимает кириллицу, поэтому слова пишутся на латинице: Privet, poka.

Распознавание идет по следующему принципу: терминал отправляет данные в буфер Arduino (эмулирую в Proteus, поэтому только что введенный символ сразу отправляется в буфер). Arduino берет пришедший символ и отправляет в метод для распознавания. А тот в свою очередь вызывает метод добавления в массив, содержащий ссылки на буквы, которые надо отобразить на матрицах.

Метод распознавания как раз и съедает всю ту память, прибавившуюся к памяти для данных. (Без него 554 байт на данные, с ним 1242)

```
void recognitionSign(String value){
  if (value == " ") { addLetter(space); }
  else if (value == "!") { addLetter(screamer); }
  else if (value == "#") { addLetter(hash); }
  else if (value == "$") { addLetter(dollar); }
  else if (value == "%") { addLetter(percent); }
  else if (value == "&") { addLetter(and_sign); }
  else if (value == "(") { addLetter(round_left); } 
  ........ // и т.д для каждого символа
```

Метод принимает тип String потому что некоторые буквы кириллицы пишут словами, окруженными "\". Например, буквы 'ы' - это "\i_sign\" (в метод приходит только "i_sign")

```
void addLetter(byte letter[]){
letterForScreen[cout_letter] = letter; 
cout_letter += 1;
}
```

Массив, хранящий знаки для отображения на экране

```
byte* letterForScreen[20];
```

Ну и соответственно после команды "старт" начитается чтение массива letterForScreen и вывод букв.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть готовые библиотеки по русификации, возможно стоило бы или использовать их, либо подсмотреть реализацию.

В вашем случае стоит посмотретьстатью: «[PROGMEM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)». В частности, используйте
`data type PROGMEM variable[] = {};` для `byte A[] = { 0x7C, 0x12, 0x11, 0x12, 0x7C };` и `F()` для  `else if (value == "!") { addLetter(screamer); }`.
Потому как  `// и т.д для каждого символа` — это просто жесть. Неужели нельзя использовать ASCII коды и не плодить это засилье `if`-ов?